# Adding Tableview to Storyboard view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Hello this might be an easy question to answer but i have been looking around and I am not able to figure the answer out. I was working with a template to add a side bar to an application. The side bar is created by using a storyboard and applying different views. Can be found here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ I tried applying this tableview example: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ I added the table view to the main view controller. For some reason no matter what I do it stays black. I have added the data source and the delegate to the main controller but still get black screen. Any thoughts? Thank you!

here is a screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: show your screen shot

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your tableview is added to the correct subview. Interface builder tends to add views to other views as subviews if they overlap each other. Check you document outline for the order and hierarchy of your tableview.

[image: Example Document Outline]

Comment: I added the table view to a view and the data source and delegate to the main view controller

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're zoomed in far enough that your tableView can be added to the viewController. I've had that problem before, and zooming in usually does the trick.

Comment: Yes I made sure i zoomed in and added it to the view

Comment: I have fixed my issue, just so you guys know when i added the tableview to the view, it automatically had added under reference outlets the main view. All I did was delete that and voila! thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue, just so you guys know when i added the tableview to the view, it automatically had added under reference outlets the main view. All I did was delete that and voila! thanks for all the help!